# Is it possible to use Spring @Retryable in @Configurable classes?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I would like to use Spring @Retryable annotation with @Configurable class. But it seems doesn't work. Is there any way to do it?

I have a legacy dao class which is out of Spring context (because it is used in classes out of Spring context). Some of data access calls are not reliable thus it was decided to give a try to @Retryable. Here an example:

```
@Configurable
public class SomeLegacyDao {

    @Autowired
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    @Retryable(value = DataAccessException.class,
            maxAttempts = 2, backoff = @Backoff(delay = 100))
    public int count() {
        return jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(...);
    }
}
```

I can't use @Component/@Repository right now because of the way the other code instantiates dao:

```
SomeLegacyDao dao = new SomeLegacyDao();
```

Comment: can you explain your use case? why do you want to retry and exactly what you want to retry?

Comment: thx. for your reply. I've updated my question with an example.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand the life cycle of spring it is not possible. When looking into the life cycle of spring (https://howtodoinjava.com/spring-core/spring-bean-life-cycle/ ) it starts with loading the Configuration. Classes annotated with @Configuration are used to instantiate Beans. The @Retryable annotation is, as far as i know, used by the Proxys that Spring creates around beans. You therefore already require a setup Context which can not be done before the configuration is loaded.

If you provide a example/reason for your use case there might be a different approach to your Problem :)

Comment: thx. I added an example to my question. Guess an aspect is gonna be the choice.